# crontab -l not showing previous job

Tags: cron, aix

Earlier we scheduled a job in crontab and jobs are running fine.  One of my teammates executed the `crontab` command; now previously scheduled jobs are not listing when you execute the `crontab -l` command in an AIX system. How to retrieve the old jobs scheduled in the crontab?

Comment: In general : when you use the crontab command to replace an existing cron schedule, the previous  one is replaced and gone. I’m not very familiar with AIX but in the Unix versions I know best, cron schedules are stored in files (`var/spool/cron` for example) and when included in your backup, you can of course restore them

Answer (score 0):

Find out the user from which you create the cronjobs.

Login to the same user and then run `crontob -l` command or you can login as a root and use `cronjob -l -u username` to check the cronjob of a specific user

Comment: when i execute crontab -l command its not showing previously scheduled jobs

Comment: it will not, read the manual of  [crontab](https://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab) it lists the current active one. thats why you should watch your logs usually ;-)

Comment: how should i retrieve old jobs now

Comment: @RAM grab the file from your backups. It'll be in `/var/spool/cron` or somewhere similar (I don't have an AIX system to check)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is not just confusion over which user's crontab is being listed (as noted in a different answer), I think it may be a case of having accidentally replaced the crontab file.

Regarding the "what to do" part: Probably restore the relevant crontab file from backup, unless it can be trivially recreated.

Regarding the "what happened" part, I am not sure of any AIX specifics, but presumably a new blank(?) crontab file was installed based on the input to that first `crontab` command. (Although the details of what exactly was done are not clear from the question).

Answer (score 0):

crontab -l command is user specific. It will show only cron jobs of user, currently you are running command as (user). You can find all your cron files on this path - /var/spool/cron/